# Pandas best practice to select multiple column data

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a very redundant code to address multiple columns of a row from a pandas dataframe. Which looks something like this:

```
info = []
info.append(row['column name'])
...
(multiple lines of mere appending)
```

And I am passing this list on to another python script that populates the returned values on a web page. I have to improve this to get rid of redundancy, and I am not sure how to go about this.

What is the best practice to do such task?

Comment: Please post more code. It is not clear (to me) where the redundancy is.

Comment: @unutbu info.append(row['column name']) repeats multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of column names.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3], 'y':[5, 6, 7], 'z':['a', 'b', 'c']})
```

select a row with `iloc` and select columns using list of names, e.g. if you only want 'x' and 'z':

```
df.iloc[1][['x', 'z']]
```

returns:

```
x    2
z    b
Name: 1, dtype: object
```